# python replace more than one key from json data in dict

Tags: python, json, dictionary, replace, duplicates

is it possible to replace more than one key in a dict from a json file.
I will try to explain my problem with simple expamples:
I have a json File like this:

```
   "a1": {
      "option": "2",
      "suboption": "2",
      "option": "2",
      "suboption_device": "3",
      "option": "1",
      "suboption_ip": "1",
      "option": "1",
      "suboption_ip": "2"
    }
```

my fist test look like this:

```
def replace_option(match):
    global o
    o += 1
    return 'option%o' % o

def replace_suboption(match):
    global s
    s += 1
    return 'suboption%s' % s

def preProcessing():
    with open('test.json') as f:    
        data = f.read()
    replace1 = json.loads(re.sub("option", replace_option, data))
    replace2 = json.loads(re.sub("suboption", replace_suboption, data))
```

so in `replace1` disappear all `suboption_ip` and in `replace2` all `option` except one.

hmm... Maybe it is possible to perform the replacement process in one method? Have annybody an idea?

Thanks for helping me :)

EDIT:

Output from `replace1`:

```
"a1": {
  "option1": "2",
  "suboption": "2",
  "option2": "2",
  "suboption_device": "3",
  "option3": "1",
  "suboption_ip": "1",
  "option4": "1",
}
```

Output from `replace2`:

```
"a1": {
  "option": "2",
  "suboption1": "2",
  "suboption2_device": "3",
  "suboption3_ip": "1",
  "suboption4_ip": "2"
}
```

Comment: Just use the `json` module to load the file. `data =json.load(f)`. That will give you a python dictionary that you can alter as normal rather than trying string formatting.

Comment: yes, but the Python dictionary takes out the duplicate keys

Comment: Then it looks like something masquerading as JSON but not valid. There should be no dupes

Comment: So you do not know any way to solve the problem ... maybe another one

Comment: @Knix Your problem is predicated on something that isn't defined. JSON may not have duplicate keys. From the spec: "When the names within an object are not unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is unpredictable."

Comment: Well,Wireshark recorded a network communication and then I exported it to json. The duplicate keys are included in the json file because the testing software can query multiple options from a device. I know that this is not defined for a json file, but still I had to handle the problem somehow, because the only key he took was the last one.

Answer (score 0):

easy with:

```
with open(INFILE, "rt") as f:    
    with open(OUTFILE_BLOCK, "wt") as o:
        for line in f:
            i += 1
            o.write(line.replace("pn_dcp.block", "pn_dcp.block%i" %i))
i = 0
with open(OUTFILE_BLOCK, "rt") as f:    
    with open(OUTFILE_OPTION, "wt") as o:
        for line in f:
            i += 1
            o.write(line.replace("pn_dcp.option", "pn_dcp.option%i" %i))
i = 0
with open(OUTFILE_OPTION, "rt") as f:    
    with open(OUTFILE_FINAL, "wt") as o:
        for line in f:
            i += 1
            o.write(line.replace("pn_dcp.suboption", "pn_dcp.suboption%i" %i))
i = z
```